# Как заполнить массив с ссылками на объекты?

Tags: c++, массивы, классы, ссылки

У меня есть класс `Figure` и класс `Rectangle`, который наследуется от `Figure`.
Есть массив `Figure* figures`, который необходимо заполнить ссылками на объекты. Эти объекты нужно создать внутри этого цикла (с заполнением массива).
Как это грамотно сделать?

PS: пробовал так:

```
Rectangle* rect = new Rectangle;
cin >> *rect;
figures[i] = rect;
delete rect;
```

Но в результате массив заполнялся одинаковыми ссылками.

Comment: В результате массив заполнялся *битыми указателями*. Не надо удалять объект сразу после его создания.

Comment: Я удаляю ссылку на объект, которую сохранил в массиве.

Comment: Или я чего-то не понимаю

Comment: `delete` удалят объект, на который ссылается указатель. соответственно тот же самый указатель, сохраненный в массиве, становится невалидным.

Comment: такие сомнительные утверждения необходимо подкреплять, приводя [mcve]

Comment: Ок, я понял. Все правильно работает.

Comment: В коде нет ни одной ссылки...

Comment: rect это ссылка на объект Rectangle